# Make div background 100% in Bootstrap fluid container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div inside a Bootstrap `container-fluid` like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-12 myDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.myDiv {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

But of course, the background of `myDiv` doesn't go all the way to the edges of the view, since `container-fluid` has `padding/margin` on it. Anyway to over come this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use bootstrap element then use class `row` so it will overcome the issue of `container-fluid` or else you can use custom class(in my case `.pd_none`).

With row [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xswz1w01/3/)

```
.myDiv {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12 myDiv row"></div>
</div>
```

---

With custom [class](http://jsfiddle.net/xswz1w01/4/)

```
.myDiv {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.pd_none{padding:0px !important;margin:0px !important;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid pd_none">
  <div class="col-md-12 myDiv ">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

For more detail here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427407/bootstrap-3-container-fluid-with-grid-adding-unwanted-padding)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override your div (not a good practice to override the divs of bootstrap, but if requirement says then we need to )

```
.col-md-12.myDiv{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0;
}
```

And this shall work.

{By default 15px pad is added on each side of the col by default}

Comment: can you please explain how it will work? as it won't work.

Comment: Currently col-md-12 has class name as mydiv, so I just gave the css for the mydiv.

mydiv being a part of grid div of bootstrap takes 15px padding on both of its sides by default. So once we give padding as 0 there that 15px is overrided and the resultant div wont take occupy those ones.

Comment: sorry but if you will try this code then you will see there is still margin means its not working. see here http://jsfiddle.net/Leo_the_lion/vqxqw1oq/

Comment: and off topic : one advise for you, when you are not able to understand the question then please don't post low answer as your both answer doesn't working so please remove them. Thanx