# Div don't cover whole width of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Div Above navigation don't cover whole width of page. And how to determine height?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxfDV.jpg)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class='col-md-12-fluid' style="
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        background-color:#FF5722;
        padding-top: 2px;
        ">
  <div class='col-md-8-fluid'> 
    <!--recently search was here--> 
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/1.jpg" height="60px" ></a> </div>
  <br>
  <div class='col-md-4-fluid'>
    <h3>Nepal Safety</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='clearfix'> </div>
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you create a fiddle or give us a test page?

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet? This isn't valid HTML. Its best if you do a snippet because we can actualy see what is happening instead of just code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 .container-fluid with grid adding unwanted padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427407/bootstrap-3-container-fluid-with-grid-adding-unwanted-padding)

Answer (score 1):

These are normally related to the margin for container

```
.container-fluid {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
}
```

You shoud redefine this class: locally  or a proper css file

```
.container-fluid {
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Changing the TWBS CSS file only works untill you update, unfortunately. I'd advice to use your own CSS to alter the padding.

Answer (score 1):

You use a `container-fluid` wich has padding at both sides.

Use the following CSS to fix this problem:

```css
body .container-fluid {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class='col-md-12-fluid' style="
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background-color:#FF5722;
    padding-top: 2px;
    ">
    <div class='col-md-8-fluid'>
                <!--recently search was here-->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
        </div><br>
        <div class='col-md-4-fluid'>
        <h3>Nepal Safety</h3>

        </div></div>

        <div class='clearfix'> </div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    </nav>
```

What also works in this case, is to replace the `container-fluid` with `row-fluid`. That gives the full width properties without `padding` and without modification.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
 </div>
```

....

Remove the `container-fluid` class and replace with `container-fullwidth`

or you can use padding both side equal to 0

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}
```

Comment: Removing the `container-fluid` impacts more then just the padding