# ReactBootstrap css Problems when importing bootstrap.min.css

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am building a React Website with ReactBootstrap. I did Navbar and Carousel with ReactBootstrap and Footer.js component with MdBootstrap. After I Imported Bootstrap.min.css on my Footer.js, the Carousel.jsx and CustomNavbar,jsx are not full width anymore.

Here my [Footer.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06PXi.jpg)

Here a [screenshot of Navbar and Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UIgg.jpg)

Here a [screenshot of the Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04UUS.jpg)

Maybe the bootstrap.min.css on my Footer.js overwrite the bootstrap.min.css ref on the index.html? I really do not know a solution.

Could please someone help me?

Thanks,

Nic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your'e using a Container without setting it to fluid.

You can have a look at the bootstrap documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)

You just need to add a `className` of `container-fluid`.

From the docs:

> Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are
> required when using our default grid system. Choose from a responsive,
> fixed-width container (meaning its max-width changes at each
> breakpoint) or fluid-width (meaning it’s 100% wide all the time).
>
> Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire
> width of the viewport.

Comment: Hi @Matan Bobi,  thanks for your reply, I added className="container-fluid" into some parts but no changes :(  here a screenshot: https://imgur.com/uqKCw18

Comment: @Nico90 That's because `className="container-fluid"` is used on Container element only. for fluid Navbar you will need to supply `fluid=true` on the component. you can look at the docs here: react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar

Comment: Hi @Matan Bobi, I got a better result adding true as you can see on this screenshot https://imgur.com/tEZSG99 here my navbar and carousel now https://imgur.com/CVCddx3 On error I read I have to put fluid=true, I do not understand where i have to write it. If I write fluid=true on the rows I get errors too.

Comment: `fluid={true}` should be set on the Navbar element only and not on all of its children.

Comment: here my code now https://imgur.com/ynDPNTJ but no changes on the navbar. Now I do not have errors messages.

Comment: Try wrapping it with a Container with `fluid={true}`

Comment: here my code https://imgur.com/QA0po33. I got a padding as you can see here https://imgur.com/vUDublr

Comment: @Nico90 have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427407/bootstrap-3-container-fluid-with-grid-adding-unwanted-padding
 Btw, This probably is a different question. the question you originally asked was solved so in that case you should open a new question if you don't find the answer already. If I answered your question, Please mark it as answered for later on searches

Comment: Ok, now I have to fix the Navbar so it will display the items inline and remove the padding right and left. For this I opened a new topic. Thank you for your help. Nico

Comment: here the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863465/display-reactbootstrap-navbar-inline