# Display ReactBootstrap Navbar inline

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, mdbootstrap

I am building a Website with react and I applied Reactbootstrap for Navbar and Carousel. For Footer MdBootstrap.

I get the Problem that my Navbar is not displayed inline and there is a padding right and left on navbar and Carousel.

Could someone please help me to fix that?

Here my CustomNavbar.jsx and CustomNavbar.css:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './CustomNavbar.css'

export default class CustomNavbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar default collapseOnSelect fluid={true}>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <Link to="/">CodeLife</Link>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle/>
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>

          <Nav>

            <NavItem eventKey={1} componentClass={Link} href="/" to="/">
              Home
            </NavItem>
  

            <NavItem eventKey={2} componentClass={Link} href="/about" to="/about">
              About
            </NavItem>
  
 
            <NavItem eventKey={3} componentClass={Link} href="/news" to="/news">
              News
            </NavItem>
  
          </Nav>
  
        </Navbar.Collapse>

      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
```

```css
nav.navbar, .navbar-default {
    background-color: #2892D7 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  
  .navbar-default {
    background-image: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: white;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
```

Here how it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dThLN.jpg

Comment: Remove the `display: block;` from `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a ` or change it to `inline-block`

Comment: I tried both but no changes. A friend of me told me it could be because I have the ref of bootstrap.min.css v3 on index.html and on app.jsx i am importing bootstrap.min.css v4. I am trying some changes with no results

Comment: You will have to build a codepen so we will be able to see the whole problem

Comment: Unfortunatly I am not able to run the pen properly but I copy pasted the code inside it. Here the link https://codepen.io/Nico90/pen/erOpXm

Comment: I made some tests and I figure out the  reactbootstrap navbar work well with bootstrap.min.css v3 and the mdbootstrap with bootstrap.min.css v4. I really do not know how to include both, as it seems they do not work properly togheter...

Comment: try upgrading to reactstrap http://reactstrap.github.io/ and build the navbar with bootstrap v4 also. remove all v3 css.

Comment: Thank you now navbar and footer works. For Carousel I have to learn more about props. This is how i fixed it: I removed all bootstrap 3 dependencies and links. I installed bootstrap 4 and used reactstrap.github.io

Answer (score 1):

Try `flex-direction: row`, it seems to be the only solution that works for me.