# What should my Angular component's top-level Bootstrap class to be, to be independent of its parent?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a component with the following markup to use the advantages of the Bootstrap grid.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">...</div>
  <div class="col-6">...</div>
</div>
```

But I had someone raise the concern that this means the component's parent then needs to deal with the `row`'s negative margins. The component should be wrapped in a `container` class to be a "complete" Bootstrap grid layout.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-6">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, if I do this, the child component now has outer gutters, which are unnecessary to this small component and creates double gutters when combined with a parent's `col` or `container` and the child's `container`.

[Per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35192643/1917171), Bootstrap doesn't trivially let you remove these outer gutters but preserve the inner gutters.

Is it possible to use Bootstrap in a component's styles without its parent having to know and deal with its child's padding choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of container class is **to help you center your contents**. If your parent element was already defined with a `.container`, I do not see any reason to nest a *direct child* with another `.container`. Like you said, it only adds double "outer gutters".

Taken from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ :

> Containers provide a means to center and horizontally pad your site’s contents. Use .container for a responsive pixel width or .container-fluid for width: 100% across all viewport and device sizes.

---

The answer you had hyperlinked refers to bootstrap 3 and not bootstrap 4. Bootstrap 4 has more [spacing utitilies](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/)

I really do not see a purpose of "removing outer gutters" because the purpose of the outer gutters is to center your contents.

However, if you requirements really need so, you can actually do so with `px-0` class in bootstrap 4.

---

#### Using .container and .row

[image]

- green dashed line is .container
- red line is .row
- as observed, containers has 15px left and right **padding**
- row has -15px left and right **margin**
- col-6 has 15px left margin. Hence, 15px - 15px + 15px = 15px

#### Using only .row (hence, with negative margins)

[image]

- row has -15px left and right margin
- col-6 has 15px left and right margin
- (-15px) + 15px = 0px. Hence, there is no "outer gutter width"  at all.

[**simple codepen example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NQbbEJ)

Comment: This is a good outline, but if I don't use a `.container` or use `.px-0`, `.row` being the top level Bootstrap class of a component will give it negative margins that need to be dealt with by its parent.

Comment: `negative margins that need to be dealt with by its parent.` are you sure you don't have custom CSS defined by yourself or your team in other stylesheets that has overriden the default margins in either .row or .col-6?. Do double check using your developer console. I have updated my answer to show that using .row only with .col shouldn't caused "negative margin" issue.

Comment: waht about use .no-gutters?

Comment: I guess it's true that the negative margins shouldn't cause an issue if you're using `.col` within. I guess I'm thinking if you were to use a component independently on the top-level, the negative margins would cause awkward scrolling behaviour. But then really, you should be expected to `.container`ize any Bootstrap thing at the top-level. I guess these examples are kind of accurate to all the possibilities and helped me logic it out.

Comment: @Eliseo .row.no-gutters removes the inner gutters as well, which isn't really desired.