# Using overflow along with sticky items in a Bootstrap layout on Firefox sometimes creates unwanted vertical space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

This is a very weird and specific bug that only happens on Firefox, and I'm having trouble narrowing it down.

I have a page with a sticky menu followed by a fluid container.
In order to remove all padding from the container while keeping everything else untouched (like column gutters), I had to add this CSS to it:

```css
#main-container {
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This is the only simple way I found to do that, and it works.
If you remove the `overflow` property, some horizontal scrolling appears.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35192643/5845942

But when I pin the menu, scroll until its position becomes fixed, and interact with certain items on the page, vertical space appears on the page, between the menu and the container.
This happens when triggering CSS transitions and other JS DOM manipulations.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vctls/mac2Ls0d/35/

A screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

And a video:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5RLo.jpg

Again, this only happens on Firefox. Chrome handles the layout without any issue.
It doesn't happen either if the menu isn't pinned, or if you remove the `overflow` property from the container.

This seems to be a Firefox bug. I found a similar issue was already reported:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1618029

I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: i do not see much difference with chrome and ff with a padding reset   `<!-- The problem only occurs with this fluid container. -->
    <div id="main-container" class=" p-0  container-fluid ">`  https://jsfiddle.net/qj82a53v/

Comment: Because you don't have the full content of my page. Using `p-0` creates other issues with colums. I've tried most other answers to the question I linked, and only this solution worked all the time, until this.

Comment: okay, your fiddle doesn't reproduce your screenshot issue with my Firefox. (latest, 64 bits  w10)

Comment: Are you sure? I tried multiple versions of Firefox, on two computers and even an Android phone, and I have the same issue. Did you use the latest fiddle?
I think I'll record a video, it will be easier to understand.

Comment: I added a video. I also added columns to the fiddle, so you can see that removing the overflow property creates horizontal scrolling.
I linked a Firefox bug report that seems to be about the same issue.

Comment: Maybe i do not totally understand your issue, width:100% seems too easy to solve your trouble ?  `<div id="main-container" class="container-fluid w-100">` https://jsfiddle.net/mojt4g3b/

Comment: You put the padding back in. I want this padding to go away. https://i.imgur.com/NBNS1pn.png And as soon as you add `padding: 0` it overflows.